# Using MATLAB spectrogram() to plot frequency (Hz) vs time (sec)

Tags: matlab, time-series, spectrogram

I would like to generate the spectrogram (power spectral density) from  a temporal signal, having the frequency in Hz on the y-axis and time in seconds on the x-axis.

I have a sinusoidal signal generated like this:

```
dt = 0.04; % Integration time step in ms
T = 10000;  % simulation time in ms -> so 10 seconds of simulation
nt = round(T/dt); % simulation steps

x = sin(2*pi*frequency*(1:1:nt)*dt/1000 + phase);
figure; plot((1:1:nt)*dt/1000, x)
```

[image]

I plot the spectrogram / power spectral density as (p.s. I am not familiar with it):

```
fs = 1000/dt;
figure; spectrogram(x, [], [], [], fs, 'yaxis', 'psd')
```

[image]

I expected the plot to be Hz-vs-Seconds but I got kHz-vs-Seconds.
Also by setting `fs=1/dt`; the plot becomes Hz-vs-Hours.

Comment: If you wanted Hz, can you just relabel the yTicks to be multipled by 1000?  Then you have Hz and can change [`ylim`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ylim.html) to be whatever you need.  Please tell me if I'm missing something.

Comment: Thank you @SecretAgentMan, by using `ylim([0, 0.012])`, `yticks(yticks*1000)`, `ylabel('Frequency (Hz)')` seems to work. But I am struggling to make the labels of the yticks visible. Do you know how to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Execute your code like you do above but then instead of `yticks(yticks*1000)` do the following:

```
% Get yRuler-object
ax = gca;
yRuler = ax.YAxis;

% Loop through TickValues, multiply and insert into TickLabels cell-array
for n = 1:numel(yRuler.TickValues)
    yRuler.TickLabels{n} = num2str(yRuler.TickValues(n) * 1000);
end
```

Not particulary concise, but it should do the job.